# Worker failed to function id and AssertionError, Azure Functions Python

Tags: azure-functions

**Issue:** I have an small *Azure Functions code* which should retrieve secrets from the *Azure Keyvault*. I'm using 2 python modules (*Azure.keyvault & Azure.Identity*). This used to work but now I'm getting an error.

**Troubleshooting:** It seems it's coming from *Azure.Identity* cause when i remove this module, I don't get any errors and when I write & run this code in default way (not Azure Functions), it works as well. Also I have versioned pinned the module (back to previous version 1.5.0 from 1.6.0), but it didn't work.

Please help me to fix this issue. I'll post the Error and my code below:
[My Code]:

[image]

[Error]:

```
    Functions:

        TimerTriggerPython: timerTrigger

    For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
    [2021-08-10T12:26:45.529Z] Worker process started and initialized.
    [2021-08-10T12:26:46.264Z] Worker failed to function id 0f918900-966c-4b13-a12e-7f29d8b28399.
    [2021-08-10T12:26:46.264Z] Result: Failure
    Exception: AssertionError: 
    Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 302, in _handle__function_load_request
        func = loader.load_function(
      File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 40, in call
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\loader.py", line 83, in load_function
        mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
      File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\TimerTriggerPython\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
      File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
        from ._credentials import (
      File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\_credentials\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from .authorization_code import AuthorizationCodeCredential
      File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\_credentials\authorization_code.py", line 8, in <module>        
        from .._internal.aad_client import AadClient
      File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\_internal\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
        from .certificate_credential_base import CertificateCredentialBase
      File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\_internal\certificate_credential_base.py", line 11, in <module> 
        from .persistent_cache import load_service_principal_cache
      File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\_internal\persistent_cache.py", line 9, in <module>
        import msal_extensions
  File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\msal_extensions\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .cache_lock import CrossPlatLock
  File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\msal_extensions\cache_lock.py", line 5, in <module>
    import portalocker
  File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\portalocker\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import portalocker
  File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\portalocker\portalocker.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 105, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\M65E083\VSOCDE_PWD_Rotation\Azure-Func-Timer-Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 99, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    assert sys.modules[modname] is not old_mod
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Switching from python 3.9 to 3.7 resolved this. I don't have an explanation for why this is, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hi Ben,  I just deploy the code to the function to Azure Cloud portal and see the results there. This is working but a bit time consuming. Thank you for your answer. Could you pls rate my questions so i get some reputations here?